# Peripherals not recognized installation windows server 2016

Tags: windows

I am trying to install windows server 2016, and i infused my windows 2016 with all USB drivers of my motherboard. When i run the bootable usb i come to the first screen and my keyboard is completely offline as well as my mouse.

i double-checked the drivers by extracting the USB drivers from windows 10 and infusing into installation media.

It seems to me as if all is rather frozen. I made this usb bootable with rufus. The drive is in legacy, all ports are legacy enabled, there is no fastboot, legacy is activated and my BIOS is prepared for this installation.

I need Multipoint Services hence newer windows server versions are out of the question.

Comment: Did you try installing the standard Windows installation without these additional drivers?

Comment: I have a standard windows 10 installed. I am trying to install server 2016 on a second HDD. Additional drivers were added as a possible solution to the problem.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I tried standard windows 10, it worked. I also tried standard 2016 , didnt work.

Comment: Why don't you in Windows 10 create a virtual machine for Windows Server 2016? You won't need then any special drivers.

Comment: I have a 2060 RTX GPU, and i am afraid in 2019 a VM cant have it forwarded as it is not in the "supported hardware" list. Hence Multipoint Services. I want to avoid having a thin client and run a dual monitor setup with two user sessions in parallel. I need forwarding so miracast is enabled.

Comment: will try simple virtualbox.

Comment: Why not Hyper-V?

Comment: hyper-V would not forward the GPU. I need a GPU driver that has miracast support. Apparently i read on a forum that oracle has it.

Comment: WSL2 has gpu forwarding for linux. But linux does not have miracast (officialy). Its a vicious circle.